# Como posso unir o restante dos dados com a 1º consulta em SQL

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-excel, select

Pessoal tenho uma consulta em SQL que me retorna os valores não duplicados da coluna: **Nº Tel**, e que tenha o **Status** igual a ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Nº Tel] FROM [export$] WHERE [Status] = "ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA"
```

Preciso agora juntar o restante das colunas que está na mesma tabela **[export]** de acordo com o resultado que eu trouxe do primeiro SELECT

> O restante das colunas são:

- [CPF/CNPJ]
- [Nº Contrato]
- [Motivo de Envio]
- [Data Ativação]
- [Data Importação]
- [Data Alteração]
- [Status]

Comment: E como se junta a primeira parte com a segunda parte? Poste exemplo, para que possamos compreender.

Comment: Deixa eu tentar ser mais objetivo, bom a primeira coisa a ser feita foi trazer os dados não repetidos, ok já está feito, mas quando eu executo está query:

SELECT DISTINCT [Nº Tel] FROM [export$] WHERE [Status] = "ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA"

Ela me mostra somente uma coluna a [Nº Tel], eu precisava que mostrasse também o restante das colunas, que são:

[CPF/CNPJ]
[Nº Contrato]
[Motivo de Envio]
[Data Ativação]
[Data Importação]
[Data Alteração]
[Status]

Precisaria ser feita uma junção do resultado do primeiro SELECT com o restante dos dados que estão presentes na tabela [export]

Comment: Magno, o que você escreveu no seu comentário anterior é o que já estava na descrição do problema. Continuo com a dúvida "como se junta a primeira parte com a tabela original?".  Se você puder acrescentar diretamente na descrição exemplos com amostra de dados (como estão; como ficaram após o SELECT; como devem ficar, ao final) , facilite compreender o que necessita. // Talvez não tenha percebido, mas se na tabela original para um mesmo telefone houver duas ou mais linhas, como decidir qual delas deve ser acrescentada ao SELECT e quais devem ser descartadas?   ;)

Comment: @JoséDiz Peço desculpas por não ter esclarecido bem as coisas e não ter dado exemplos, mas acabou que irei ficar somente com aquele SELECT mesmo, mas vi que você tem bastante conhecimento com Banco de Dados, e fiz uma outra pergunta e nela explico certinho, dou exemplos, e ainda posto a query que tentei realizar, se você puder me ajudar, pois realmente preciso, mas meu conhecimento com Banco de Dados não é tão grande, aqui está o link do post: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/361821/como-verificar-dados-diferentes-e-obter-o-primeiro-registro-em-sql

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    MIN([Nº Tel]),
    [CPF/CNPJ],
    [Nº Contrato],
    [Motivo de Envio],
    [Data Ativação],
    [Data Importação],
    [Data Alteração],
    [Status]
FROM
    [export$]
WHERE
    [Status] = "ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA"
GROUP BY
    [CPF/CNPJ],
    [Nº Contrato],
    [Motivo de Envio],
    [Data Ativação],
    [Data Importação],
    [Data Alteração],
    [Status]
```

Comment: Na verdade essa query é a mesma coisa que eu selecionar os campos que preciso e que esteja com ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA, não diferenciou nada para mim.

Comment: Tem certeza, patrão?! Pq se isso não resolve seu peoblema, então eu não entendi qual a dificuldade que você está enfrentando.

Comment: Então, mano acabei por ficar com o aquele SELECT mesmo, mas fiz uma outra pergunta aqui no Stack Overflow de uma outra regra, lá eu sou bem objetivo, demonstro exemplos, e também apresento uma tentativa que fiz, se puder me da aquela força, agradeço: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/361821/como-verificar-dados-diferentes-e-obter-o-primeiro-registro-em-sql