# Como verificar dados diferentes e obter o primeiro registro em SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, microsoft-excel

Preciso criar um filtro em SQL que segue algumas regras, tenho uma planilha no Excel e nela preciso aplicar o filtro a seguir, a planilha possui os campos:

- GSM
- MOTIVO_ENVIO
- DATA_ATIVACAO
- DATA_IMPORTACAO
- DATA_ALTERACAO
- STATUS

> Filtro:
>
> ---
>
> **GSM** que se repete e tiver o **STATUS** = "PENDENTE", "EM ANÁLISE" mas o seu **MOTIVO_ENVIO** for diferente, importe somente a linha que tiver o **STATUS** igual a "ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA"

Eu tentei de muitas maneiras, mas sem sucesso, não tenho tanto conhecimento com Banco de Dados e por isso gostaria da ajuda de vocês, o mais longe que consegui foi:

```
SELECT [GSM],
       [MOTIVO_ENVIO],
       [DATA_ATIVACAO],
       [DATA_IMPORTACAO],
       [DATA_ALTERACAO],
       [STATUS]
FROM [export$] AS export
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT aux.[GSM]
     FROM [export$] AS aux
     WHERE export.[GSM] = aux.[GSM]
       AND [STATUS] = "PENDENTE")
  AND [STATUS] = "ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA"
```

Mas não consegui colocar uma das partes mais importantes do filtro:

> ...o seu **MOTIVO_ENVIO** for diferente, importe somente a linha que tiver o **STATUS** igual a "ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA"

A baixo segue um exemplo de como seria a estrutura que é encontrada na planilha, basta agora aplicar o filtro para que eu consiga extrair a "ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA" de acordo com as regras mencionadas.

[image: Filtro realizado para exemplo.]

Gostaria muito do Help de vocês, desde já agradeço!

Comment: Compartilha a tabela com alguns dados, pode ser no pastebin no sharecsv ...

Comment: @thiaguerd claro que sim, aqui está ela completa: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wXHhvI9In4j_lrwB3dzcyHsm5jThlkcQ/view

Comment: Eu troquei os nomes das colunas, as alterações foram: Nº Tel = GSM | Motivo de Envio = MOTIVO_ENVIO | Data Ativação = DATA_ATIVACAO | Data Importação = DATA_IMPORTACAO | Data Alteração = DATA_ALTERACAO | Status = STATUS | irei editar o post pra deixar tudo certinho :)

Comment: Cola esta sua planilha em formato de tabela para eu reproduzir seu cenário e tentar de ajudar.

Comment: @Ismael https://drive.google.com/open?id=1S1KKp6qKw1nykDK4nZRWO0O4CzZRxAS0

Comment: Eu não tenho acesso :( a empresa restringe, então, possuo algumas limitações... A pergunta precisaria ser editada.

Answer (score 1):

A dificuldade continua em entender o que você precisa, mas vamos lá, por partes.

Entendi que você precisa de: GSM que se repete e tiver o STATUS = "PENDENTE", "EM ANÁLISE"

Você acha essa resposta com:

```
select
    count(gsm) as "repeticoes_do_gsm",
    gsm
from
    expt
where
    status in  ('PENDENTE', 'EM ANÁLISE')
GROUP BY
    gsm
HAVING
    count(gsm) > 1
```

Continuando, você disse que: "mas o seu MOTIVO_ENVIO for diferente, "

Aí eu te pergunto, MOTIVO_ENVIO for diferente do que?

Enumera aí o que mais você precisa, passo a passo, sem medo.